# Error 100 XMLHttpRequest failed Parse query

Tags: parse-platform

I'm successfully performing this query:

```
var Photo = Parse.Object.extend("Photo");
var query = new Parse.Query(Photo);
query.equalTo("SOMEID", parseInt(SOMEID));
query.limit(25);
query.descending("createdAt");
query.find({
  success:function(results) {
  // Some code to work with the objects returned    
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

from this domain:

```
mydomain.com/index.html
```

but the exact same query fails from another page:

```
mydomain.com/someother.html
```

The error is:

```
code: 100
message: "XMLHttpRequest failed: {\"onabort\":null,\"onerror\":null,\"onload\":null,\"onloadend\":null,\"onloadstart\":null,\"onprogress\":null,\"ontimeout\":null,\"timeout\":0,\"readyState\":4,\"withCredentials\":false,\"upload\":{\"onabort\":null,\"onerror\":null,\"onload\":null,\"onloadend\":null,\"onloadstart\":null,\"onprogress\":null},\"responseText\":\"\",\"responseXML\":null,\"responseType\":\"\",\"response\":\"\",\"status\":0,\"statusText\":\"\",\"responseURL\":\"\"}"
```

Might not be a domain issue, but I'm a little lost in why I'm getting this error back from parse.  Any ideas?